# Number of possible joint policies in a Dec-POMDP and the time required to evaluate each one

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

I was reading a book about Dec-POMDPs and came across this curious result where the author specifies the number of possible joint policies to evaluate and the time needed to evaluate a single joint policy but I can understand how he got to these results.

Can anyone please help me understand the logic used here?[image]

Source: "[Reinforcement Learning: State-of-the-Art](https://books.google.com/books?id=YPjNuvrJR0MC&pg=PA480&lpg=PA480&dq=%22optimal+deterministic+joint+policy%22+for+a+finite+horizon+DEC-POMDP&source=bl&ots=BUEyeoqmTt&sig=ACfU3U0q8mx8s-V2HV6kd7rk99kGSuHdVw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTvNj8jr34AhU2C0QIHXTrB5wQ6AF6BAgtEAM#v=onepage&q&f=false)", Editors Dr. Marco Wiering &
Dr. ir. Martijn van Otterlo Radboud, DOI 10.1007/978-3-642-27645-3, Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg 2012.

Comment: What book were you reading? What don't you understand specifically and what you understand? Edit your post to include this info. Moreover, reformulate the title in the form of a question. Thanks.

Comment: Which part of the argument in the source are you having trouble with?